# maven can't add libraries

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, maven

I Create a project with Maven in intellij.I add dependencies and in local i check that repository was made. I dont have any error with dependencies but no library doesn't add . help me please. this is my pom code :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.baharan</groupId>
<artifactId>uni</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>


<build>
    <plugins>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

and this is my hibernate configuration xml that don't know mysql and hibernate and take error

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
            "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
            "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

```
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project2
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
        root
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
      root
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" >true</property>
    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
    <mapping class="Student"/>
    <mapping class="Course"/>
</session-factory>
```

Comment: Did you create setttings.xml im maven directory ? https://maven.apache.org/settings.html

Comment: @LukaszCiesluk Thanks a lot . i didn't know that i should do that . thank you so much . I try it

Answer (score 0):

You have missed to add the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in your pom file..

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Afterwards you should be able to create your Spring Boot application via:

```
mvn clean package
```

on plain command line.